# Thymeleaf removes empty placeholders in html template file

Tags: java, templates, thymeleaf

I am in a position of parsing a template file in two steps.

Consider I have a template as below.

```
<html>
   <img th:attr="src='${imageSourcePath}'"/>

   <span th:text="${someText}"></span>
</html>
```

and Context object as below.

```
Context ctx = new Context();
ctx.setVariable("imageSourcePath","path/To/Image.png"); 
String proccessedTemplate = templateEngine.process("templateName",ctx);
```

**Note 1 :**

> At this point I have only `imageSource` in my context object and there
>   is no `someText` in it.

Now I want to process this template file and return the processed content as below where I will process this content again with a new context object to replace the remaining placeholders.

```
 <html>
    <img src="path/To/Image.png"/>  

    <span th:text="${someText}"></span>
 </html>
```

But it is returning as below by removing the placeholders which is not present in context object.

```
     <html>
        <img src="path/To/Image.png"/>  

        <span></span>        <-- Here placeholder is removed.
     </html>
```

**Note 2 :**  I cannot have all the context variables at the same time. My requirement is to process the template in two stages.

How can I solve it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which "placeholder" are you talking about? There is no placeholder there. Also I do not see where do you specify value for `someText` variable in context/

Comment: @Andremoniy Since am new to thymeleaf I donno its exact terminologies on how to call `${imageSource}` in html template file. And am referring to the same as `placeholder`.    And regarding the `someText` variable, I have another context object with this `someText` which I will use it to process the template once again.

Comment: This just isn't something that thymeleaf supports... if you absolutely must get it to work, then you can do some pretty hackish stuff, but I would not recommend it.  Something like `<th:block th:utext="'<span th:text=&quot;${someText}&quot;></span>'"/>` (lol).

Comment: @Metroids Otherwise is there any alternative for thymeleaf which supports this functionality. I know I shouldn't be asking this question. But still it would help me a lot. And thanks for your previous response.